# How to read java.net.http.HttpRequest body as byte array(byte[])?

Tags: java, java-11

We are using Java 11 and use java.net.http.HttpClient APIs for calling REST APIs. We have the requirement of [signing the request message with API Key](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-08) before sending to the server.  Would like to know how to read the java.net.http.HttpRequest body as a byte array (byte[]) for use with the library that is used for signing the request.

Comment: one can think over the lines of subscribing to the `ByteBuffer` published via `HttpRequest.BodyPublisher`.

Comment: You can [publish a `byte[]` directly](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html#ofByteArray(byte%5B%5D)), meaning you'd have the array ahead-of-time.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816226/how-to-read-the-body-of-a-httprequest-in-java-11

Comment: You're thinking of this back to front. You should be signing the *stream* that is going *into* the HTTP request.